# Installed Flash plugin version 13 - video still not working

Tags: flash, 14.10

I just installed Ubuntu Gnome 14.10 Utopic Unicorn and I updated the Flash plugin to version 13. I checked Firefox "add-ons" and visited http://tsn.ca and http://ufc.com. Both websites claimed that I "needed to install Flash."

The bottom line: I can't stream live video. YouTube works fine.

Comment: Only flash 11 is available for firefox; where did you get 13?  Chrome has an updated version of flash, but which is not compatible with firefox, so make sure you haven't gotten that.

Answer (score 0):

I've dealt with this before. There appears to be a difference between the Flash plugin that is installed within the browser, and the one that works better.

(This also seems to resolve the issue of videos spontaneously stopping and restarting themselves in Firefox and Chrome.)

I recommend using Synaptic to check this, but the instructions below are for the terminal...as you probably don't need me telling you what to click in Synaptic, ha ha.

```
sudo apt-get remove flashplugin-installer
```

That removes the rather glitchy version that gets parked in the browser when you install from the Adobe Flash website.

```
sudo apt-get install adobe-flashplugin
```

(For the record, that one is version 11. Version 13 is not yet available for Firefox, as user7134 correctly stated.)

That installs the plugin, which works a LOT better. That's the only one I have installed on my Ubuntu 14.14 system, and Firefox and Chrome are quite happy.

Comment: PS: Don't ever expect flash 12/13/... for linux (and, eventually, Windows). They stopped active development in 2012 and will only provide bug fixes and security updates.